# How to get values from input boxes and save to database with button click angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm still learning to programme on AngularJS.
I want to get values from the input box and then click on the button I want to save them in the database.
My database table is called **"user"**. I have columns like **id**, **username**, **password**, **name**.
I have two **checkbox.When** I click on first **checkbox(Edit)** it displaying **"div myVar"**,when i click on second **checkbox(Add new user)** it displaying **"div myVar1"**.
I want to activate this button **"Add"** to add input box values to database **MySQL**. Please help me.

I have this html code:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar">Edit</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar1">Add new user</label>
    <div ng-show="myVar">
    <div class="form">
    <form ng-submit="saveItem(userForm.$valid)" name="userForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="database_address">User</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="activeItem.username" placeholder="Потребителско Име..." />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="password" ng-model="activeItem.password"  />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Operator</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="username" ng-model="activeItem.name" />
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Save</button>
            <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Добавяне на нов</button>-->
        </form><form ng-submit="createUser(userForm.$valid)" name="userForm1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="database_address">User</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="usernamee" placeholder="Потребителско Име..." />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="passwordd"required id="password"   />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Operator</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control1" ng-model="namee" required id="username"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="createUser();" type="submit">Add user</button>
    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Добавяне на нов</button>-->
</form>
```

And Angular code:

```
 $scope.createUser=function()
{
    //console.log($scope.activeItem);
        //delete $scope.activeItem.hash_method
        var objectToSave = {
            username: $scope.usernamee,
            password: $scope.passwordd,
            name: $scope.namee,
            id: $scope.id
        };
         {
            defaultAdapter.query('INSERT INTO users(username,password,name,id) VALUES(username = :usernamee, password = :passwordd,name = :namee WHERE id =:id)',
              { replacements: objectToSave, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE }
            ).then(projects => {
              console.log(projects);
              $scope.editMode = false;
                $scope.activeItem = false;
                $scope.refresh();
            });

        }


    }
```

Comment: I would suggest to use reactive form then your life will be easy

Comment: If you're using angularjs, you should use angularjs tag instead of angular tag. Also, unless you have a good reason to learn angularjs (first angular version), I would suggest you to learn angular instead (current on version 7)

Comment: I'm never using reactive and angular. I started working before one week on position junior web developer with php...but now they give me this project on angular..Please help